# How to achieve smooth transition between pages in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to achieve smooth transition between pages using material-ui `<Slide>` component when i am using [Modernize Free React MUI Dashboard](https://adminmart.com/product/modernize-free-react-mui-dashboard). My current code snippet.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react- 
    router-dom';
 import { Slide } from '@mui/material';
 import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
 import AboutPage from './pages/AboutPage';

 const App = () => {
 return (
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
  </Switch>
  </Router>
 );
 };

export default App;
```

Actually i wants smooth transition between page when click on sidebar menu buttons. Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found an effective way to handle page transitions using Material-UI and React Router? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your navigating components in the `Slide` wrapper to get a `transition` effect when *navigating* on the pages using **MUI Slide**. Let me make it simple:

**App.tsx**:

```js
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

**Your Page Component:**

```js
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <Slide direction="down" in={true} timeout={500}>
      {/* Your component */}
    </Slide>
  )
}
```

Similarly, you can create the other pages as well.

**Making code less repetitive:**
While following this approach, you must wrap all your components with this piece of code providing all the props each time. This violates the principle of *DRY*. To prevent this, you can create a common page wrapper that will have the `Slider` as the main component with all the props prefilled. Also, it will take the other components as children. Here is how you can do it:

**PageLayout Component:**

```js
const PageLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Slide direction="down" in={true} timeout={500}>
      {children}
    </Slide>
  )
}
```

**Using PageLayout:**

```js
const MyPage = () => {
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <div>....</div>
    </PageLayout>
  )
}
```